# How to set own sentences to SentencesAnnotation.class

Tags: java, annotations, stanford-nlp

I am new to **Stanford CoreNLP**. I have few sentences which I want to **type cast** those **String sentences** to **List** and set it to `annotation.set(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class, sentences);`

Any way to do the above task ?

Answer (score 0):

You must fill a `List<CoreMap>` object, the code below will give you a hint on how to do it sentence by sentence. But there other field to fill up, you can find a complete code [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/WordsToSentencesAnnotator.java)

```
List<String> yourSentences = ...;
int tokenOffset = 0;
List<CoreMap> sentences = new ArrayList<CoreMap>();
for(String s: yourSentences ){
  List<CoreLabel> tokenizedSentence = tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(
            new StringReader(s)).tokenize();
  Annotation sentence = new Annotation(text.trim());
  sentence.set(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class, tokenizedSentence);
 tokenOffset += sentenceTokens.size();
            sentence.set(CoreAnnotations.TokenEndAnnotation.class, tokenOffset);
            sentence.set(CoreAnnotations.SentenceIndexAnnotation.class, sentences.size());
  sentences.add(sentence);
}
```

Comment: I have followed the same link which you have given in your answer. I need to set parse tree by using String sentence or by using List<CoreMap> sentences.